# i want to set ng-true-value from $scope

Tags: angularjs

```
<input id="chekboxgst" type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedOrder.cbGST" 
       ng-true-value=" .17 " ng-false-value="0">
```

I want to get ng-true-value from `{{companyGST.GST}}`

Comment: Why didn't you enter `companyGST.GST` as the value for `ng-true-value`?

Comment: i had tried it but it is not working callmekatootie

Comment: Did you try with the `{{ }}` brackets? That is `ng-true-value="{{companyGST.GST}}"`

Comment: yes i did that ng-true-value="{{companyGST.GST}}"

Comment: also ng-true-value=" ' {{companyGST.GST}} ' "

Comment: Try using `{{companyGST.GST}}` directly in the template and see if AngularJS replaces it with a value. If not, it means that there is not value for that expression itself and thus cannot be bound to `ng-true-value`

Comment: it is confirm that there is value in {{companyGST.GST}}

Comment: now i am trying 
ng-true-value="applyGST()"
$scope.applyGST = function ()
    {
        return $scope.companyGST.GST;
    }
can it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that directly with ng-true-value, but you can call a function every time the value changes in order to change the value of your model.

See this [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dCANVpRH1Fyof6m8QgST?p=preview).

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedOrder = {
    cbGST : 0
  };

  var companyGST = {
    GST: 'test'
  };

  $scope.setValue = function(value) {
    $scope.selectedOrder.cbGST = value ? companyGST.GST : 0;
  };
});


<input id="chekboxgst" type="checkbox" ng-model="foo" ng-change="setValue(foo)" />
```